# Send Tracking information email to customer when tracking number saved to Magento

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6, shipment, shipment-tracking, ecommerce-tracking

Is there a way for Magento2 to send tracking information email to the customer when tracking information is saved?

Currently, we are using 3rd party tool ecomdash to process the order and shipment, and it use SOAP API to send back the tracking information to Magento 2, however, it does not notify the customer with email. Is there a way to trigger the "Send Tracking Information" when Magento received the tracking info?

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793824/programmatically-send-email-when-shipping-tracking-number-is-set

Comment: @where I have read through it, but not really sure how to implement it. Can you explain a little details? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though a long time has passed, answering for anyone else that might need it.
When calling the ship api at: `/V1/order/{orderId}/ship`, there is a `notify` key you can pass, thus causing Magento to send a notification, so your JSON might look something like:

```
{
  "notify": true, // This causes the client notification email
  "tracks": [
    {
      "track_number": "1Y-9876543210",
      "title": "Some Title",
      "carrier_code": "custom"
    }
  ]
}
```

See more here: https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/salesShipOrderV1/salesShipOrderV1ExecutePost